# Oracle SQL Materialized view after refresh statement... is there such a thing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, materialized-views

I want to run some code after a materialized view refreshes.  Is there some sort of "after" syntax that lets me run code after a materialized view refreshes?

I keep getting google hits talking about refreshing a materialized view after a statement, but that's the complete opposite of what I want to do.  I want to run a statement (basically call an API) after the materialized view has refreshed.

Thanks,

john

Comment: Not sure what is " after the materialized view has refreshed". Generally, the refreshing activity never ends as underlying master data are updated. I can imagine something like "a moment when the materialized view has refreshed" only within a single transaction scope.

Comment: What causes the refresh of the materialized view? If it is done by a (scheduler) job then append your code to this job. If it is triggered by application then add your code there.

Comment: Maybe create a statement DML trigger on the base table(s)

Comment: When I have read the question third time I realized you do not need something like `execute dbms_mview.refresh('test_mv','f');` Sorry, cheers! :)

Comment: Maybe you can take the info from this: `select * from user_mview_refresh_times;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's preventing you from creating an after-insert trigger on the mview?

**POC**

```
Connected to Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 

SQL> create materialized view mv_test
SQL>     build deferred
SQL>     refresh complete with rowid on demand
SQL> as
SQL> select *
SQL> from c_country
SQL> ;

Materialized view created

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_mv_test_after_insert
SQL>     after insert on mv_test
SQL> begin
SQL>     dbms_output.put_line('the mview has been refreshed at '||systimestamp);
SQL> end;
SQL> /

Trigger created

SQL> begin
SQL>     dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST','C');
SQL>     dbms_session.sleep(1);
SQL>     dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST','C');
SQL>     dbms_session.sleep(2);
SQL>     dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST','C');
SQL>     dbms_session.sleep(1);
SQL>     dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST','C');
SQL> end;
SQL> /

the mview has been refreshed at 15.11.19 09:30:51,686000000 +01:00
the mview has been refreshed at 15.11.19 09:30:52,729000000 +01:00
the mview has been refreshed at 15.11.19 09:30:54,768000000 +01:00
the mview has been refreshed at 15.11.19 09:30:55,805000000 +01:00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```

Works like a charm!

**Footnotes**

Of course, a fast-refreshable mview may require additional triggering points -- `delete`, `update`.

Play with your use case and find your ultimate solution yourself.